# Make /etc/nginx writable, so I can edit it from the network

Tags: ubuntu, samba, nginx

I'm running Win10 with Ubuntu Server 14.04 on a VM.

I shared my website folder (`/var/www`) with samba (I ran `chown -R www-data:www-data`) and it's writable. I edit the files with Sublime (on Win10) and it's all good.

Now I did the same with nginx folder (`/etc/nginx`) so I can edit the `nginx.conf` and sites configurations as well, but it's not writable.

Comment: What happens when you type `ls -lat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`?

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root`, I tried chown and chmod at `/etc/nginx`.

Comment: Looks like the owner is root and you can only overwrite as root. Why not try `sudo chmod 646 nginx.conf` or just simply `sudo vim nginx.conf`?

Comment: Why does it work on the file, but when I run it at the folder It's stops the share?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that making `nginx.conf` or any config file for that matter world-writable is a very bad idea. In fact, many services won't even start with such a permissions setup.

Comment: It's only my local webserver, where I'm developing and testing. I changed to ubuntu server because now I'm working with Dreamhost. So I wanna testing things on the same enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do this at any kind of web server connected to the internet, but if it makes you happy, try to access samba as root instead of your user account. Create a password for user root and try to connect to your share with that:

```
smbpasswd -a root
```

Best log out of windows and log back in, AFAIR windows only supports one authentication connection to a server. (Or fumble around with the net command to disconnect from the samba server, but a logout should be faster. :))